# JQUERY Remote Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, contextmenu

Having problems with dynamically (remote) loaded Context Menus. I don't know how to use $.getJSON to add attributes to the Items command list... I'm very new to JQUERY and JSON. Been looking for answers for days and can't seem to get it right.

```
The backend test CGI scripts produces the following JSON data:

Test 1)         ["name":"test","icon":"edit"]
Test 2)         ["Choice1", "Choice2","test1","test2"]

(Test 2 I was able to get working with another set of code, but not this one)
```

Both fail to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Right Click</title>
    <link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
    $.contextMenu(
    {
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) 
        {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },


        //Nasty block of code Start
        items: function( request, response ) 
        {
                var url = "http://192.168.1.9/cgi-bin/test.cgi";
                $.getJSON(url, 
                {
                        tagmode: "any",
                        format: "json"
                })
                .done(function(data) 
                {
                        $.each(data.items, function( i, item ) 
                    {
                        //put into list???
                    });
                });
        }
        //Nasty block of code End



    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e)
    {
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })
    });
</script>


<div class="context-menu-one">
<input id="word" size="50">
</div>
```

End Goal: To have an input box where users can click on words they've typed and on the back-end do a search to provide a menu of options. (A fancy text editor for very specific business needs) I'm pretty familiar with Perl and the back end won't be tough... I'm having problems building the front-end UI. As a side note these menus might get big... so any performance gains you might suggest would be useful.

What do I need to do to get this code working properly? Please provide a demo if possible.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be perfect but this is the solution I found.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <title>Right Click</title>
        <link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var options = {};
        options.items = {};
        get_word();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
        $.contextMenu(
        {
                selector: '.context-menu-one',
            build: function($trigger,e) 
            {
                return get_word();
            },
            items: $(options)
            });
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function get_word ()
        {

            var url = 'http://192.168.1.9/cgi-bin/test3.cgi?';
            var cgi = "term=test";
            var submit = url + cgi;
            $.ajax(
                {
                            url: submit,
                            type: 'get',
                            cache: false,
                            async: true,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (_result) 
                    {
                        $.each(_result, function(item, index)
                        {
                            var object = {name:[index],icon:"edit"};
                            options.items[index] = object;
                            console.log("-",index);
                        });
                        return options;
                            }
                });
            return options;
        }


        });
</script>





<div class="context-menu-one">
    <input id="word" size="50">
</div>

<div class="helpIcon">
    <a href="http://192.168.1.9/cgi-bin/test3.cgi">test</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```